# Rails 3.1: How to query based on result of method?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my app, I would like to maintain chainability across ActiveRecord queries. But 
I am not always able to do so. Sometimes I am forced to use select - which returns an Array
thereby destroying chainability.

In particular, I have a model called Response in my app

Response has a method called page? which returns the page number - an integer - for 
the particular Response object

```
def page?
  ... returns the page number ...      
end
```

The method - page? - needs to look at some other models in the app in order to perform.
It cannot - in other words - rely solely on data in the Responses table

Right now, I have a query - on_page(n) - defined as follows in Response model class

```
 def self.on_page(n)
   select{ |m| m.page? == n }
 end
```

Problem is that the above select returns an Array and not an ActiveRecord::Relation.
Which means that I cannot do the following ( 'with_scan' is another ActiveRecord query )

```
Response.on_page(3).with_scan
```

I can get the above to work by changing the order in which queries are done. But thats just a hack

Is there an alternative to using select in the 'on_page' query? Or a different way of using it? Any way in which chainability could be maintained?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Abhinav

Answer (score 0):

Chainability is accomplished by working with instances of ActiveRecord::Relation.  To turn an instance of Array into ActiveRecord::Relation, use the .scoped() method:

```
def self.on_page(n)
   select{ |m| m.page? == n }.scoped
end
```

You can view the documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).